# Using Log4j2 in WebApps

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, log4j2

I'm currently writing a web app using Servlet 3.1. According to the Log4j2 website 
`Log4j 2 "just works" in Servlet 3.0 and newer web applications.`. But whenever I start the server (Tomcat 8.0.5), I get an error `Error processing element RandomAccessFileAppender: CLASS_NOT_FOUND`. When I lookup the class using eclipses "Open Type", I see that this class exists and is in the package org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="off" packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender">
    <Appenders>
        <RandomAccessFileAppender name="DEFLOG" ignoreExceptions="false" fileName="${web:rootDir}/log/log.log">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %C{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
        </RandomAccessFileAppender>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="trace">
            <AppenderRef ref="DEFLOG"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

This log4j2.xml file is located under src/log4j2.xml, the Log4j2-jars "log4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar" and "log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar" are located under WEB-INF/lib/.

Comment: Sadly, no. But I haven't tried in a while

Comment: The solution is so simple... I asked the question today, too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23906301/1183192 It must be RandomAccessFile instead of RandomAccessFileAppender

Comment: God damn it. Well, know I know.

Comment: I noticed you didn't mention the log4j-web jar, just thought I'd mention that the [log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/webapp.html) says "...you'll need to add the log4j-web module to your deployment..."