# Log4j2 does not write logs to a file

Tags: java, slf4j, log4j2

I am using log4j2 with slf4j and I want to write my logs to a file. This is my log4j2.xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>
        <RandomAccessFileAppender name="Logfile"
            fileName="\\domain\path\logs\log.txt">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </RandomAccessFileAppender>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Logfile" />
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Logging to the console works, but I do not get any logs in the file. I get the following error message on the console:

```
2014-05-28 10:17:01,164 ERROR Error processing element RandomAccessFileAppender: CLASS_NOT_FOUND
2014-05-28 10:17:01,309 ERROR Unable to locate appender Logfile for logger
```

Why does log4j not find the class? Do I have to use additional dependencies?

Comment: Documentation says there is no RandomAccessFileAppender but RandomAccessFile. Try to change it.

Comment: You have the log4j-core.jar in your classpath?

Comment: Facepalm, facepalm, facepalm... I have read the docs, but I wrote the heading of RandomAccessFileAppender section, since it looks like a class name... Thank you!